# What is the correct way to calculate no of days between two dates in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date

I am currently working with nepali dates. Since there is no simple logic behind end of the month and it can be 29, 30, 31 and 32. I need no of days between two date in specific logic.

I have tried following code:

```
    $from = '2076-07-15';
    $to = '2076-07-30';

    $from_array = explode('-', $from);
    $to_array = explode('-', $to);

    $days = $to_array[2] - $from_array[2];
```

This gives no of days as 15 which is correct however in following case,

```
$from  = '2076-07-01';
$to = '2076-07-15';
```

Output will be 14 but output I want is 15 since there are 15 days from 1 to 15.

Example outputs I want are:

```
From       To            Required  Current

2076-07-01 2076-07-15 => 15 days   14 days -----> Incorrect
2076-07-15 2076-07-30 => 15 days   15 days ------> Correct
2076-07-01 2076-07-30 => 30 days   29 days ------> Incorrect
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Note: There will be year and month value same for from and to variable, only day field is different

Comment: laravel? just use `Carbon`, or just simply use `DateTime` classes, don't use string manipulations like explode of some sort

Comment: @Kevin I can't use Carbon because I am working with local date here in nepal, it's not an english date, Some month can have 32 days

Comment: Then you need to convert it to English date and use carbon there is no other ways bro. I am also from Nepal.

Comment: what about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552708/3859027 this uses nepali format in conjuction with `Carbon/DateTime`

Comment: Hello @CHARITRASHRESTHA, can you suggest me a date convertor compatible with laravel ?

Comment: @Kevin That just displays english date in nepali language not in nepali date ;)

Comment: ok, wait for fo a while I will give you my code.

Comment: Sorry, "Output will be 14 but output I want is 15 since there are 15 days from 1 to 15."

But according your output:
2076-07-15 2076-07-30 => 15 days   15 days ------> Correct

It should be wrong too, because there are 16 days from 15 to 30

Comment: Use Carbon: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Comment: difference between 1 and 15 is 14 days,not 15 days..so the code is correct i think.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this code in some place accessible for you and use the last example method provided. And that will convert the Nepali into English and vice versa. And then use Carbon to subtract the dates.

```
Nepali into english and vice versa converter
```

```
<?php
namespace App\Helper;

class Nepali_Calendar
{
    // Data for nepali date
    private $_bs = array(
        0 => array(2000,30,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        1 => array(2001,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        2 => array(2002,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        3 => array(2003,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        4 => array(2004,30,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        5 => array(2005,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        6 => array(2006,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        7 => array(2007,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        8 => array(2008,31,31,31,32,31,31,29,30,30,29,29,31),
        9 => array(2009,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        10 => array(2010,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        11 => array(2011,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        12 => array(2012,31,31,31,32,31,31,29,30,30,29,30,30),
        13 => array(2013,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        14 => array(2014,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        15 => array(2015,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        16 => array(2016,31,31,31,32,31,31,29,30,30,29,30,30),
        17 => array(2017,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        18 => array(2018,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        19 => array(2019,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        20 => array(2020,31,31,31,32,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        21 => array(2021,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        22 => array(2022,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,30),
        23 => array(2023,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        24 => array(2024,31,31,31,32,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        25 => array(2025,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        26 => array(2026,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        27 => array(2027,30,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        28 => array(2028,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        29 => array(2029,31,31,32,31,32,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        30 => array(2030,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        31 => array(2031,30,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        32 => array(2032,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        33 => array(2033,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        34 => array(2034,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        35 => array(2035,30,32,31,32,31,31,29,30,30,29,29,31),
        36 => array(2036,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        37 => array(2037,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        38 => array(2038,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        39 => array(2039,31,31,31,32,31,31,29,30,30,29,30,30),
        40 => array(2040,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        41 => array(2041,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        42 => array(2042,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        43 => array(2043,31,31,31,32,31,31,29,30,30,29,30,30),
        44 => array(2044,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        45 => array(2045,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        46 => array(2046,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        47 => array(2047,31,31,31,32,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        48 => array(2048,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        49 => array(2049,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,30),
        50 => array(2050,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        51 => array(2051,31,31,31,32,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        52 => array(2052,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        53 => array(2053,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,30),
        54 => array(2054,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        55 => array(2055,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        56 => array(2056,31,31,32,31,32,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        57 => array(2057,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        58 => array(2058,30,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        59 => array(2059,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        60 => array(2060,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        61 => array(2061,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        62 => array(2062,30,32,31,32,31,31,29,30,29,30,29,31),
        63 => array(2063,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        64 => array(2064,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        65 => array(2065,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        66 => array(2066,31,31,31,32,31,31,29,30,30,29,29,31),
        67 => array(2067,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        68 => array(2068,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        69 => array(2069,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        70 => array(2070,31,31,31,32,31,31,29,30,30,29,30,30),
        71 => array(2071,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        72 => array(2072,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        73 => array(2073,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,31),
        74 => array(2074,31,31,31,32,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        75 => array(2075,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        76 => array(2076,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,30),
        77 => array(2077,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,29,31),
        78 => array(2078,31,31,31,32,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        79 => array(2079,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,29,30,29,30,30),
        80 => array(2080,31,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,29,30,30),
        81 => array(2081,31,31,32,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,30,30),
        82 => array(2082,30,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,30,30),
        83 => array(2083,31,31,32,31,31,30,30,30,29,30,30,30),
        84 => array(2084,31,31,32,31,31,30,30,30,29,30,30,30),
        85 => array(2085,31,32,31,32,30,31,30,30,29,30,30,30),
        86 => array(2086,30,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,30,30),
        87 => array(2087,31,31,32,31,31,31,30,30,29,30,30,30),
        88 => array(2088,30,31,32,32,30,31,30,30,29,30,30,30),
        89 => array(2089,30,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,30,30),
        90 => array(2090,30,32,31,32,31,30,30,30,29,30,30,30)
    );

    private $_nep_date = array('year' => '', 'month' => '', 'date' => '', 'day' => '', 'nmonth' => '', 'num_day' => '');

    private $_eng_date = array('year' => '', 'month' => '', 'date' => '', 'day' => '', 'emonth' => '', 'num_day' => '');

    public $debug_info = "";

    /**
     * Return day
     *
     * @param int $day
     * @return string
     */
    private function _get_day_of_week($day)
    {
        switch ($day)
        {
            case 1:
                $day = "Sunday";
                break;

            case 2:
                $day = "Monday";
                break;

            case 3:
                $day = "Tuesday";
                break;

            case 4:
                $day = "Wednesday";
                break;

            case 5:
                $day = "Thursday";
                break;

            case 6:
                $day = "Friday";
                break;

            case 7:
                $day = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
        return $day;
    }

    /**
     * Return english month name
     *
     * @param int $m
     * @return string
     */
    private function _get_english_month($m)
    {
        $eMonth = FALSE;
        switch ($m)
        {
            case 1:
                $eMonth = "January";
                break;
            case 2:
                $eMonth = "February";
                break;
            case 3:
                $eMonth = "March";
                break;
            case 4:
                $eMonth = "April";
                break;
            case 5:
                $eMonth = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                $eMonth = "June";
                break;
            case 7:
                $eMonth = "July";
                break;
            case 8:
                $eMonth = "August";
                break;
            case 9:
                $eMonth = "September";
                break;
            case 10:
                $eMonth = "October";
                break;
            case 11:
                $eMonth = "November";
                break;
            case 12:
                $eMonth = "December";
        }
        return $eMonth;
    }

    /**
     * Return nepali month name
     *
     * @param int $m
     * @return string
     */
    private function _get_nepali_month($m)
    {
        $n_month = FALSE;

        switch ($m)
        {
            case 1:
                $n_month = "Baishak";
                break;

            case 2:
                $n_month = "Jestha";
                break;

            case 3:
                $n_month = "Ashad";
                break;

            case 4:
                $n_month = "Shrawn";
                break;

            case 5:
                $n_month = "Bhadra";
                break;

            case 6:
                $n_month = "Ashwin";
                break;

            case 7:
                $n_month = "kartik";
                break;

            case 8:
                $n_month = "Mangshir";
                break;

            case 9:
                $n_month = "Poush";
                break;

            case 10:
                $n_month = "Magh";
                break;

            case 11:
                $n_month = "Falgun";
                break;

            case 12:
                $n_month = "Chaitra";
                break;
        }
        return $n_month;
    }

    /**
     * Check if date range is in english
     *
     * @param int $yy
     * @param int $mm
     * @param int $dd
     * @return bool
     */
    private function _is_in_range_eng($yy, $mm, $dd)
    {
        if ($yy < 1944 || $yy > 2033)
        {
            return 'Supported only between 1944-2022';
        }

        if ($mm < 1 || $mm > 12)
        {
            return 'Error! month value can be between 1-12 only';
        }

        if ($dd < 1 || $dd > 31)
        {
            return 'Error! day value can be between 1-31 only';
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    /**
     * Check if date is with in nepali data range
     *
     * @param int $yy
     * @param int $mm
     * @param int $dd
     * @return bool
     */
    private function _is_in_range_nep($yy, $mm, $dd)
    {
        if ($yy < 2000 || $yy > 2089)
        {
            return 'Supported only between 2000-2089';
        }

        if ($mm < 1 || $mm > 12)
        {
            return 'Error! month value can be between 1-12 only';
        }

        if ($dd < 1 || $dd > 32)
        {
            return 'Error! day value can be between 1-31 only';
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates wheather english year is leap year or not
     *
     * @param int $year
     * @return bool
     */
    public function is_leap_year($year)
    {
        $a = $year;
        if ($a % 100 == 0)
        {
            if ($a % 400 == 0)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ($a % 4 == 0)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * currently can only calculate the date between AD 1944-2033...
     *
     * @param int $yy
     * @param int $mm
     * @param int $dd
     * @return array
     */
    public function eng_to_nep($yy, $mm, $dd)
    {
        // Check for date range
        $chk = $this->_is_in_range_eng($yy, $mm, $dd);

        if($chk !== TRUE)
        {
            die($chk);
        }
        else
        {
            // Month data.
            $month  = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);

            // Month for leap year
            $lmonth = array(31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);

            $def_eyy     = 1944;    // initial english date.
            $def_nyy     = 2000;
            $def_nmm     = 9;
            $def_ndd     = 17 - 1;  // inital nepali date.
            $total_eDays = 0;
            $total_nDays = 0;
            $a           = 0;
            $day         = 7 - 1;
            $m           = 0;
            $y           = 0;
            $i           = 0;
            $j           = 0;
            $numDay      = 0;

            // Count total no. of days in-terms year
            for ($i = 0; $i < ($yy - $def_eyy); $i++) //total days for month calculation...(english)
            {
                if ($this->is_leap_year($def_eyy + $i) === TRUE)
                {
                    for ($j = 0; $j < 12; $j++)
                    {
                        $total_eDays += $lmonth[$j];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for ($j = 0; $j < 12; $j++)
                    {
                        $total_eDays += $month[$j];
                    }
                }
            }

            // Count total no. of days in-terms of month
            for ($i = 0; $i < ($mm - 1); $i++)
            {
                if ($this->is_leap_year($yy) === TRUE)
                {
                    $total_eDays += $lmonth[$i];
                }
                else
                {
                    $total_eDays += $month[$i];
                }
            }

            // Count total no. of days in-terms of date
            $total_eDays += $dd;


            $i           = 0;
            $j           = $def_nmm;
            $total_nDays = $def_ndd;
            $m           = $def_nmm;
            $y           = $def_nyy;

            // Count nepali date from array
            while ($total_eDays != 0)
            {
                $a = $this->_bs[$i][$j];

                $total_nDays++;     //count the days
                $day++;             //count the days interms of 7 days

                if ($total_nDays > $a)
                {
                    $m++;
                    $total_nDays = 1;
                    $j++;
                }

                if ($day > 7)
                {
                    $day = 1;
                }

                if ($m > 12)
                {
                    $y++;
                    $m = 1;
                }

                if ($j > 12)
                {
                    $j = 1;
                    $i++;
                }

                $total_eDays--;
            }

            $numDay = $day;

            $this->_nep_date['year']    = $y;
            $this->_nep_date['month']   = $m;
            $this->_nep_date['date']    = $total_nDays;
            $this->_nep_date['day']     = $this->_get_day_of_week($day);
            $this->_nep_date['nmonth']  = $this->_get_nepali_month($m);
            $this->_nep_date['num_day'] = $numDay;
            return $this->_nep_date;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Currently can only calculate the date between BS 2000-2089
     *
     * @param int $yy
     * @param int $mm
     * @param int $dd
     * @return array
     */
    public function nep_to_eng($yy, $mm, $dd)
    {
        $def_eyy     = 1943;
        $def_emm     = 4;
        $def_edd     = 14 - 1;  // initial english date.
        $def_nyy     = 2000;
        $def_nmm     = 1;
        $def_ndd     = 1;       // iniital equivalent nepali date.
        $total_eDays = 0;
        $total_nDays = 0;
        $a           = 0;
        $day         = 4 - 1;
        $m           = 0;
        $y           = 0;
        $i           = 0;
        $k           = 0;
        $numDay      = 0;

        $month  = array(
            0,
            31,
            28,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            30,
            31
        );
        $lmonth = array(
            0,
            31,
            29,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            30,
            31
        );

        // Check for date range
        $chk = $this->_is_in_range_nep($yy, $mm, $dd);

        if ( $chk !== TRUE)
        {
            die($chk);
        }
        else
        {
            // Count total days in-terms of year
            for ($i = 0; $i < ($yy - $def_nyy); $i++)
            {
                for ($j = 1; $j <= 12; $j++)
                {
                    $total_nDays += $this->_bs[$k][$j];
                }
                $k++;
            }

            // Count total days in-terms of month
            for ($j = 1; $j < $mm; $j++)
            {
                $total_nDays += $this->_bs[$k][$j];
            }

            // Count total days in-terms of dat
            $total_nDays += $dd;

            // Calculation of equivalent english date...
            $total_eDays = $def_edd;
            $m           = $def_emm;
            $y           = $def_eyy;
            while ($total_nDays != 0)
            {
                if ($this->is_leap_year($y))
                {
                    $a = $lmonth[$m];
                }
                else
                {
                    $a = $month[$m];
                }

                $total_eDays++;
                $day++;

                if ($total_eDays > $a)
                {
                    $m++;
                    $total_eDays = 1;
                    if ($m > 12)
                    {
                        $y++;
                        $m = 1;
                    }
                }

                if ($day > 7)
                {
                    $day = 1;
                }

                $total_nDays--;
            }

            $numDay = $day;

            $this->_eng_date['year']    = $y;
            $this->_eng_date['month']   = $m;
            $this->_eng_date['date']    = $total_eDays;
            $this->_eng_date['day']     = $this->_get_day_of_week($day);
            $this->_eng_date['nmonth']  = $this->_get_english_month($m);
            $this->_eng_date['num_day'] = $numDay;

            return $this->_eng_date;
        }
    }
}

//  Example:
//  $cal = new Nepali_Calendar();
//  print_r ($cal->eng_to_nep(2008,11,23));
//  print_r($cal->nep_to_eng(2065,8,8));
```

Just you need to copy and paste and magic happend.

Comment: I am having still same issue, when I enter date like 2076-07-01 to 2076-07-30 it gives 29 days but I want 30

Comment: bro 30-1 always gives 29. if you want  the inclusive subtraction you need to add 1 at last solution. I think your logic is incorrect somewhere. You can use the converter to get the difference if you want to get the subtraction between to different t months date.

Comment: May be you are right but thats the requirement, 30 to 15 must be 15 and 30 to 1 should be 30

Comment: date subtraction works in their own exlcusive way. You can add one at the end so that you will get your desired output.

Comment: if this answer helps you please upvote the answer and select it as the correct answer. Support the community

Comment: Sure bro, Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $datetime1 = new DateTime("05-07-2019");
 $datetime2 = new DateTime("10-08-2021");
 $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 echo 'Difference: '.$difference->y.' years, ' 
           .$difference->m.' months, ' 
           .$difference->d.' days';
```

It will give an output

```
Difference: 2 years, 1 months, 5 days
```

If you want difference in days only.use

```
echo 'Difference: '.$difference->format('%a').' Days';
```

Output will be

```
Difference: 767 Days
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to use `nesbot/carbon` package https://carbon.nesbot.com/#gettingstarted.

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

$from = Carbon::parse('2076-07-15');
$to = Carbon::parse('2076-07-30');
$days = $from->diffInDays($to);
```